# Please don't suggest starting a bounty to users who are unable to do so

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035681/bookmarklet-that-detects-whether-the-current-page-is-a-result-of-a-get-request-or) that went for a long time without getting a definite answer. Later, when I looked at my user page, I saw the text "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?". I tried to figure out how to start a bounty, and read through the FAQs, and eventually found out that I can't offer a bounty unless I have at least 100 reputation points. So my suggestion is to not suggest starting a bounty to users who are unable to do so.

Comment: That seems like a pretty straight forward suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In 2009, 10 days after this question was asked, Jeff Atwood (I think you all know he was one of the creators of Stack Overflow) tagged this question as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). So, I think it pretty evident the bug was fixed at that time.