# Where did the add bounty link go?

Tags: support, bounties

I'd like to add a bounty to my question, but I can't find out how to add the bounty. I looked on my account page, on the page of the question itself and in the edit view..

I have a reputation of 84 which should suffice.

[nopony http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/7027/nobountypony.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/7027/nobountypony.png)

[choppy graphics when drawing xna on a winforms control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357434/choppy-graphics-when-drawing-xna-on-a-winforms-control)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You [need at least 75](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5338/please-dont-suggest-starting-a-bounty-to-users-who-are-unable-to-do-so) rep before you can slice off your ear and offer it up to someone as part of a bounty.

Questions must also be at least 2 days old, as mentioned in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/)

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Answer (score 7):

It's below "add comment" of your question:

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/1600/bountypony.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/1600/bountypony.png)

Click the link and move the slide along to select how much you want to pay on the bounty.

[image: more bang for your bounty]

Comment: @random: Don't mess up my art!

Comment: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/7027/nobountypony.png no bounty pony for me :( is the question too fresh or is it my rep?

Comment: Didn't see your edit before putting in those lame brick screenshots. Was caught on the edit screen too long.

Comment: the upvoting of this answer doesn't really help as the add bounty is clearly absent on my end as can be seen on the screenshot..

Comment: The upvoting is clearly for the animals. Not sure about the bloke trying to blow things up. Like blowing up your rep? What-what!

Comment: Much better, random, much better :) @Wouter: there is a waiting period before you can call a bounty. Have to look up how long it is...

Comment: Voted up for the answer first, could not upvote any harder for the donkey.