# Don't suggest starting a bounty if a bounty is active

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I am getting "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963254/netbeans-sftp-download-only-new) where a bounty is active, already. Maybe "Have you considered accepting an answer for this question?" would be better here.

Comment: Can be "linked" to [this case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5338/please-dont-suggest-starting-a-bounty-to-users-who-are-unable-to-do-so) - instead of just checking the user reputation, check each question if it's eligible for a bounty (same check that is performed to decide whether or not to show the "Start a bounty" link)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will no longer show the bounty message if there is an open bounty for a question.

Comment: Was the change rolled back? See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128926/bug-asking-me-to-start-a-bounty-on-a-bounty-question).