# Bug: asking me to start a bounty on a bounty question

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't suggest starting a bounty if a bounty is active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120831/dont-suggest-starting-a-bounty-if-a-bounty-is-active)

When I look at my questions list (for instance this link https://stackoverflow.com/users/786284/javo?tab=questions) I can see there a question where I already started a bounty.

In spite of that I can see a label asking me to start a bounty on this question

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

In this case it's about question [Positioning of classes in UML diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020822/positioning-of-classes-in-uml-diagram) where I already started a bounty.

I don't think there should be a label about starting a bounty if I already did it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120831/dont-suggest-starting-a-bounty-if-a-bounty-is-active) it was already "fixed" - maybe the fix has been rolled back for some reason.

Comment: For some reason I can't see the bounty messages on _any_ of my unaccepted qns in the question list. And I distinctly recall seeing them before. This may be due to the fact that I've offered a bounty and thus the system knows that I know what a bounty is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was certainly a check we *had* in place, but due to some data not being pulled back from the database since the user profile refactor (`BountyCloses`, `BountyClosed` and `BountyAmount` on the `Post`).  This caused the checks of "has no active bounty" to *pass* instead of fail, which *used* to stop the message from showing in the "hey man, it already had a bounty" case.

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Any chance you're now showing only one such message even if user has more than one question with unaccepted answer? In [gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7652/shadow-wizard?tab=questions) I got about 3 questions that should have that message but only one is showing. Initially thought it's related.

Comment: @Sha - no, no rules for that, but questions older than 60 days stop showing the message so....